# not calling Display.update() causes program to crash

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I am writing a 3d editor for a game in opengl using LWJGL. I only want the editor to render when i need it to. However if you only render once and keep calling `Dislplay.update()` the image glitches and if you only call `Dislplay.update()` occasionally instead of in a while loop the program stops responding and windows turns it off. Does anyone know why this is or a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accually figured it out myself after playing around a bit. Everytime you update the display it swaps buffers so either manually swap buffers every second update so it keeps using the same buffer or render twice; once for each buffer.
For example if you had a render() method to render your image you would do this:

```
render();
Display.swapBuffers();
render();
```

and then you would update the display normally.

Comment: This kind of workaround will only work if the buffer swap is a true swap. If it is a destructive blit you're out of luck. Avoid this by copying the finished rendering into a texture and in the idle display handler just draw this texture to a viewport filling quad. BTW: You can accept your own answer to mark the question being solved; you'll be awarded no reputation of course.